# Teams SSO / Access token exchanging

Tags: azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-msal

For a Teams app that has SSO enabled, once a user has authenticated and the app obtains the user's access token, can that token then be exchanged for an oauth token from a different, external service provider? Or must that user authenticate a second time for the app to be able to make API calls to that second provider? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to change an access token obtained from one provider for an OAuth token to a different provider, but this would requires some configurations and set up between the two providers.

For example, if your app has SSO enabled using Microsoft AAD as the identity provider, and you want to exchange the AAD access token for an OAuth token from  Google, you would need to set up a trust relationship between AAD and Google.

Comment: Thanks Bryce for the response. Would [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/workload-identities/workload-identity-federation-create-trust?pivots=identity-wif-apps-methods-azp#other-identity-providers) be the appropriate documentation I should look into?

Comment: Yes, if you use AAD this would be the one. You might also want to checkout the document of other external service provider you want to work with, they usually have slightly different implementation.